# Updating a Duration Field by Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Has anyone had to update a `Duraton` field from within a plugin?

On the UI it is fairly intelligent, you can type

- `5 minutes`
- `7 //defaults to minutes`
- `3 hours`

And it will workout what you need.

Assuming the field is called `new_foo`, what value should I assign? Int?

```cs
var e = new Entity("new_bar");
e.Attributes("new_foo", 5);//5 minutes?
```

Double?

```cs
var e = new Entity("new_bar");
e.Attributes("new_foo", 5.00);//5 minutes?
```

Other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Duration` is a format for the `Whole Number` type, so by code you need to set an `Int32` value (in this case not negative or it will throw an exception)

The value is always considered in minutes, so if you want to put 3 hours you need to set the field value to 180 (60 minutes x 3 hours), 1 day is 1440 (60 minutes x 24 hours) and so on.

By interface you can set using decimals, but it's always a representation of an integer value (for example 1.5 hours equals 90 minutes)