# MS Dynamics CRM online calculated field error

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, calculated-field

I have a custom entity, Duration calculation, which is used to calculate duration of Sales stage on Opportunity. In that entity, I have a calculated field which calculates duration between the stage start time and endtime (image attached). When I try to save the error is shown "Invalid XAML formula". What's wrong in this ?

[image]

Comment: The editor accepts it if I use any formula other than "DiffInMinutes" which is used in first step. Wierd!!! But it doesn't do the job, since I want to have minimum time units to calculate the duration.

Comment: Are the fields both Date & Time fields?

Comment: Yes, they are both date and time fields.

Comment: Duration is it a wholenumber or decimal?

Comment: Have you upgraded to Update 1 ?

Comment: I have the same issue in a brand new CRM Online 2016 environment (8.0.1.88). I tried with a whole number field formatted as Duration, or as "None". My formula is pretty much an exact replica of yours, except I just test End Date so my conditions are simpler (I am creating the records in workflow so I know they must have a start date).

Answer (score 0):

according with the image you are train to set the field "Duration", the result of the function DiffInMinutes is possibly a Negative number, and assuming that "Duration" is a Whole Number typed "Duration" this will throw an exception

a similar problem was consulted related to set a duration attribute using a Plugin ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148303/updating-a-duration-field-by-plugin/16149126))

Could try to make the DiffInMinutes between EndTime and StartTime instead of StartTime and EndTime

Hope it helps